# How to suppress unneeded InstallShield InstallScript MSI dialogs?

Tags: dialog, installshield

I have an InstallShield 2009 'InstallScript MSI' project which shows 2 dialogs which are not necessary in my installation:

```
Customer Information
  Setup Type
```

How can I disable those 2 dialogs?   Under 'User Interface', the 'All Dialogs' tree lists those dialogs, but they are all grayed out, and cannot be disabled or changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For InstallScript MSI (and for that matter, InstallScript) setups, you control which dialogs are shown by going to the InstallScript view. Insert the OnFirstUIBefore event by fiddling with the dropdowns at the top. Then figure out the pattern of gotos and which dialogs are shown, and rewire it to skip these dialogs. Generally the functions that show dialogs are named with the prefix `Sd`.

Comment: Basic MSI works completely differently. To disable everything use `/qn` or `/qb` on the command-line. For single dialogs, go into the surrounding dialogs' behavior nodes. Change the `NewDialog` events on the `Next` and `Back` buttons to refer to the following (or preceding) dialog instead of the one you want to remove. Note that sometimes there's more than one each preceding and following dialog to modify.

Comment: In Installshield Premier 2013 version I am not able to find surrounding dialogs behavior nodes.

Comment: I found out! :) UserInterface -> Dialogs -> double click one of the dialog which you want to change ->click on behavior -> change as you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Namely - you can not to delete a dialogue.
But you can to hide it

For this, in the perameters of visibility of whole of unwanted dialogue window you need to change it from "visible" to "hidden".

Profit!